# String operation to copy number of character to a new string location for example S[0]

Tags: c++, string

Suppose I have

```
string s1="100000111010"
string s2;
```

what is the best way to have

```
s2[0]="1000"
s2[1]="0011"
s2[2]="1010";
```

Comment: What do you mean by `s2[0] = "1000"`? `s2[0]` should be a single character.

Comment: Please show a minimal example. It likely should be less than 10 lines.

Comment: No. it's not. s2[0] location get all 4 characters.

Comment: You can't set it like that. `s2[0]` is a single character.

Comment: string B = "101010101010";
 string C;

 for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
  C[0] = B.substr(0, 3);

 }

Comment: If you want `s2[0]` to return a string, `s2` needs to be a vector or array of strings, not a string.

Comment: The goal is to divide the string as number of 4 and get those value individually to a new string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The elements of a `std::string` are `char`s, not themselves strings.  That means that `s2[0]` cannot be `"1000"` because `"1000"` is not a `char`, it is a string.

If you want to split `s1` into multiple strings, you have to split it into *multiple* strings.  For this I would use a `std::vector<std::string>`:

```
int main() {
    std::string s1 = "100000111010";
    std::vector<std::string> splits;

    for (int i = 0; i < s1.size(); i += 4) {
        splits.push_back(s1.substr(i, 4));
    }
}
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/70e9f194a2d52f48)